# Android System Apps

Tags: android

I want to filter all the applications that connect to the internet. But I do not want to display system apps like dialer or settings. However, if I use ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM, the built-in browser and youtube is also filtered. How can I get through this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the permission for the installed applications. Get the installed applications package name and their permissions like this:

```
ArrayList<PackageInfo> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);

for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    PermissionInfo[] permission = p.permissions;
    String description = (String) p.applicationInfo.loadDescription(pm);
    String  label= p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    String packageName = p.packageName;
    String versionName = p.versionName;
    String versionCode = p.versionCode;
    String icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
//Continue to extract other info about the app...
}
```

**Permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Comment: but how can I differentiate it with the system apps?